# Shields.io badge for latest GitHub pre-release excluding later release

Tags: github, shields.io

How can I create a shields.io badge that will display the latest pre-release, excluding later releases?

The behavior allows for inclusion of a later pre-release, but I want to separately list the latest released version and the latest pre-release version, even when the latest released version is greater than the last pre-release.

E.g.

```
![GitHub Latest Pre-Release)](https://img.shields.io/github/v/release/ptr727/PlexCleaner?include_prereleases&label=pre-release&logo=github)  
![GitHub Latest Release)](https://img.shields.io/github/v/release/ptr727/PlexCleaner?logo=github)
```

[image: GitHub Latest Pre-Release)]
[image: GitHub Latest Release)]

From the [GitHub Releases](https://github.com/ptr727/PlexCleaner/releases) the last pre-release version was `2.7.10-ga8a94550e6`.

The behavior works until I merge from develop to main, and then the release version supersedes the pre-release version, and the badge no longer works as expected.

How do I get the latest GitHub pre-release excluding non-prerelease builds?